# Unity and circular dependency resolution by injecting IUnityContainer

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

Unity has a problem with circular references. My current design is similar to the composite model e.g.

```
public interface IInterface {
}

public class Implementation : IInterface{
    [Dependency]
    public IInterface[] Children{get;set;}
}
```

I would like the collection of IInterface that is injected into Implementation.Children to contain all implementations of IInterface (including the class Implementation).

One solution I have is to dynamically resolve the Children property at runtime rather than the IOC inject them. But to be able to do this I need to get access to the IUnityContainer.

Is it possible to inject IUnityContainer into Implementation?

I do not want a global singleton of the IUnityContainer due to the fact that these classes are used by different applications each initializing/instantiating the container differently.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to inject IUnityContainer into Implementation?

You can just declare the container as a dependency:

```
[Dependency]
public IUnityContainer Container { get; set; }
```

The container will inject itself into the property; you don't even need to register it explicitly.